# How to get rid of the bottom panel in gnome 3 classic session

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-shell-extension

I know questions that sound like this one have been asked before, but none of the "solutions" are working for me. I am using *Gnome Classic* option.

- I could not find any extension that does what I want.
- I could not find any entry for `gnome-panel` in my dconfEditor

Will you please help me.

I installed Gnome 3 using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. I am talking of the panel visible in the following picture:

[image: gnome3 classic - bottom panel]

These are the list of extensions I have installed:

[image: List of installed gnome shell extensions - part1]
[image: List of installed gnome shell extensions - part2]

Comment: Now that you have added the bit about "GNOME Classic", I'm pretty sure Sneetsher's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- It is the Window List plugin the same one used in Gnome Shell standard session which comes within `gnome-shell-extensions` package. It's full name:

  ```
  window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
  ```

  Installed in: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`
- What it seems happening is .. the Gnome Classic session use it as a required plugin. So it does ignore disabling it. (Using `gnome-tweak-tool`)
- To get rid of it, move it somewhere else or delete it

  ```
  sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
  ```
- To re-enable it, copy it back or reinstall `gnome-shell-extensions`.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-extensions
  ```

Comment: Disabling it didn't work. I deleted the extension and worked.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 16.04, Gnome desktop (no Unity), simply start the Tweak Tool  and disable and/or remove the extension, "Window List".

Answer (score 8):

To check the current panels:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list
['top-panel-0', 'bottom-panel-0']
```

Set the panel which you want to stay visible with <sup>Tried in Ubuntu 12.04</sup>:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list "['top-panel-0']"
```

which will leave you with only the top-panel like you see in the snapshot below.

[image: snap1]

(With that done I wasn't able to `Super + W` or `Alt + tab` the minimized windows. But I haven't checked with other dock apps.. I suppose they'll work.)

To use both the panels again just run:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list "['top-panel-0', 'bottom-panel-0']"
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04. error: `No such schema 'org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout'`

Comment: I installed `gconf-editor` but could not locate the entry to hide the buttom panel. This trick works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apparently GNOME shows an option to delete panels on Alt + right click. On some machines it can be Alt + Super (the "windows" key) + right click. A menu should appear with the option to delete. If not, then I'm sorry.

EDIT: Didn't see the comment chain where you said that. weird stuff.

Comment: naah, thats not working

Answer (score 1):

onwards ubuntu 17.xx

just rename the metadata.json file in

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com$
```

and restart the system it will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a JavaScript extension such as this one which removes the bottom bar: https://sourceforge.net/projects/removebottombar/files/gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar-3.2-1.src.tar.gz/download

Comment: Can you tell me how to install it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install gksu if it isn't already, then press Alt+F2 which opens a small window. Type 'gksu nautilus' (without the quotes) and navigate to usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ , right-click window list and rename it. I named it window-lizt which disabled the extension.